# Iterating through group to get layer names in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

Can somebody provide me some source code in PyQGIS 3.4 to iterate through groups and list out the layernames?

In the image you see several groups and single layers.

The purpose is to build a dialogbox with a list of layers but only those layers with a type of Point geometry.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a list of map layers only in Point geometries (no MultiPoint), you can use :

```
points_layers = [pvl for pvl in [vl for vl in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if vl.type() == 0] if pvl.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.Point]
```

`QgsProject.instance()` : the QGIS instance singleton ;

`.mapLayers()` : return a Python dictionnary with the map layers id as keys and the layer object as values ;

`vl.type() == 0` : only vector layers ;

`.geometryType()` : only Point layers ;

**EDIT**

A more simple way to do this, just by using PyQGIS API :

```
qmlcb = QgsMapLayerComboBox()
qmlcb.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
qmlcb.show()  # this line to try in QGIS console
```

[Here the documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMapLayerComboBox.html)

Comment: Thnxs J. I almost understand it. Excerpt the expression. Can I place that on a single line? Because I get errors about indentation etc and I'am not such a Python programmeur... Yet. Can you write it out with tabs/indents?

Comment: It can be placed on one single line. Indentation (beginning of the line) depends to where you paste this line in your code.

Comment: I've added a more QGISish and nicer solution.